# How to OneWayBind to materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, reactiveui, material-design-in-xaml

I have a login button that I would like to apply an indeterminate progress look to while the login process is happening.

Here is the XAML for the button:

```
<Button x:Name="LoginButton" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}" 
        materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.Value="-1"
        materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="false"
        materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndeterminate="true">
    LOGIN
</Button>
```

So I figure I can just bind a boolean property on my view model to `materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible`.  I'm using code behind binding like so:

```
public partial class Connection : ReactiveUserControl<ConnectionViewModel>
{
    public Connection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = ViewModelLocator.ConnectionViewModel;

        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.LoginCommand, v => v.LoginButton).DisposeWith(d);
            // How do I bind to this property using OneWayBind?
            this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.LoggingIn, v => v.LoginButton.ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible).DisposeWith(d);
        });
    }
}
```

Intellisense doesn't pick up on that material designs dependency property.  How do I reference it?

*In case it matters, the WPF project targets .NET Core 3.1*

Comment: Where does materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible comes ?

Comment: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/aa26914ed87e0490756585fac80db3019e8a4fde/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/ButtonProgressAssist.cs#L86

Comment: I don't think you can access it based on that code. They haven't used a property as per standard but a get/set method instead. Xaml binding might work since it uses the dependency property directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `OneWayBind` method supports attached properties but you could bind to it in the XAML markup:

```
materialDesign:ButtonProgressAssist.IsIndicatorVisible="{Binding LoggingIn, Mode=OneWay}"
```

You can of course do `OneWayBind` for the other properties just like before.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid you were going to say...  I'm not using the XAML `DataContext` at all since I am (wanted to) do all binding with `WhenActivated`.  So now I do need to wire up `DataContext`?  No problems doing both at the same time I assume (as long as I don't bind the same thing in both places)?

Comment: Duh.  "You can of course do `OneWayBind` for other properties just like before."  Not enough caffeine yet this morning I guess.  Binding in the XAML like this does get the job done.  Thanks.